# Unable to collect static files on google cloud

Tags: django, google-cloud-platform

Hello All I am unable to render static files of my django project which is hosted on GCP. My configuration:

```
#Static Files

GS_BUCKET_NAME = 'my_bucket_name'
GS_PROJECT_ID = 'my_id'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = "storages.backends.gcloud.GoogleCloudStorage"
STATICFILES_STORAGE = "storages.backends.gcloud.GoogleCloudStorage"
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static')

STATIC_URL = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/my_bucket_name/static/'

GS_CREDENTIALS = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'service_account.json'))
#End
```

I ran collectstatic. static files are copied on my gcp bucket but I am getting this error - Could not load Google Cloud Storage bindings. Error is coming at this line `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'admin/css/main.css' %}">`. Did not find specific solution. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the steps you have taken and more details about the issue for the clarification?